# Visualizing faceted data using interactive plotting in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, data-visualization, plotly, ggvis

I'm having some trouble creating interactive plots in shiny that facet my data.
Here's some code that shows what I want, but it uses `ggplot2` which is not interactive.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

x <- 1:10000
dt <- data.frame(a = 1:100, b = sample(x,100,replace=T), c = sample(x,100,replace=T), d = sample(x,100,replace=T))
dt.molten <- melt(dt,id.vars="a")


ui <- fluidPage(
   plotOutput("gplot")
)

server = function(input, output) {

  output$gplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(y.molten,aes(x = value)) + 
      geom_histogram(binwidth = 100000) + 
      facet_wrap( ~ variable,ncol = 1)

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In my actual app, the amount of facets varies, so I can't simply hard code in 3 separate plots using `highcharter`, `ggvis`,or `plotly`.

Ideally I'd like it to look something like this:

```
require(highcharter)
x <- stl(log(AirPassengers), "per")
hchart(x)
```

Except with histograms instead of time-series data.

The main issue is that the data i'm plotting stretches over like -3,000,000 to +3,000,000 with a high concentration around 0.  This makes it hard to see the bars at the edges, so I'd like for users to be able to zoom into certain ranges of the plot without having to select it via some ui element.

I'm open to suggestions using any plotting method in R, although i'd like to stay away from `rCharts`.

EDIT: I did discover that using `plotly::ggplotly` almost achieved what I'm looking for, however it isn't very clean. I did `g <- ggplot(*plot code*)` then `ggplotly(g)`.  Works decent, but it'll take quite a bit of work to clean up I think.

Comment: You can do make interactive plots `shiny` using ggplot2.  Overview [here](https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/06/16/shiny-0-12-interactive-plots-with-ggplot2/) and example of zooming specifically [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-zoom.html).

Comment: That's a solid option, thanks.